# How to use OPA Gatekeeper to change GKE deployments?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, open-policy-agent

I am trying to use OPA Gatekeeper to modify certain Kubernetes deployments. In this example I want to change the display name of service accounts, regardless of what the user provided. So far I was following the documentation here: https://open-policy-agent.github.io/gatekeeper/website/docs/mutation/

I have created the following yaml file:

```
apiVersion: mutations.gatekeeper.sh/v1alpha1
kind: Assign
metadata:
  name: change-sa-name
spec:
  applyTo:
  - groups: [""]
    kinds: ["IAMServiceAccount"]
    versions: ["v1beta1"]
  location: "spec.displayName"
  parameters:
    assign:
      value: "New Name"
```

and used the following to deploy a service account:

```
apiVersion: iam.cnrm.cloud.google.com/v1beta1
kind: IAMServiceAccount
metadata:
  labels:
    label-one: "value-one"
  name: iamserviceaccount-sample
spec:
  displayName: Example Service Account
```

However, upon deploying it the display name still shows up as Example Service Account and not New Name. What exactly am I doing wrong or what should I be looking at?

Answer (score 1):

As per the [official docs](https://cloud.google.com/config-connector/docs/reference/resource-docs/iam/iamserviceaccount#schema) you need to give the display name as you are wishing to give at row displayName. Find below yaml and try it, if you get errors paste it here.

```
apiVersion: iam.cnrm.cloud.google.com/v1beta1
kind: IAMServiceAccount
metadata:
  labels:
    label-one: "value-one"
  name: iamserviceaccount-sample
spec:
  displayName: <Give the display name that you are looking for>
```